# group or unpivot df not considering empty values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, unpivot

I have a df like this :

| PRODUCTNUMBER | Jerarquía principal | Jerarquía secundaria marcas | COT | Ecommerce | dabra-catalog | Dexter-ecommerce | Stockcenter-ecommerce |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AD802309 | Medias-Hombre | ADIDAS | 950699 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| AD481076 | NaN | Adidas | 950699 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| AD481137 | Medias-Hombre | Adidas | 950699 | Medias-Hombre | Medias-Hombre | Medias-Hombre | Medias-Hombre |

and I need to get this output:

| PRODUCTNUMBER | PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME | PRODUCTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AD802309 | Medias-Hombre | Jerarquía principal |
| AD802309 | ADIDAS | Jerarquía secundaria marcas |
| AD802309 | 950699 | COT |
| AD481076 | Adidas | Jerarquía secundaria marcas |
| AD481076 | 950699 | COT |
| AD481137 | Medias-Hombre | Jerarquía principal |
| AD481137 | Adidas | Jerarquía secundaria marcas |
| AD481137 | 950699 | COT |
| AD481137 | Medias-Hombre | Ecommerce |
| AD481137 | Medias-Hombre | dabra-catalog |
| AD481137 | Medias-Hombre | Dexter-ecommerce |
| AD481137 | Medias-Hombre | Stockcenter-ecommerce |

is it possible? "NaN" values must not be transposed

Comment: It seems that you want to not have NaN values show up in your final dataframe. Would you be fine with pivoting your dataframe then removing any NaN values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `melt`

```
out = df.melt('PRODUCTNUMBER',
               value_name='PRODUCTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME',
               var_name='PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME').dropna()
Out[201]: 
   PRODUCTNUMBER          PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME PRODUCTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME
0       AD802309          Jerarquía principal                Medias-Hombre
2       AD481137          Jerarquía principal                Medias-Hombre
3       AD802309  Jerarquía secundaria marcas                       ADIDAS
4       AD481076  Jerarquía secundaria marcas                       Adidas
5       AD481137  Jerarquía secundaria marcas                       Adidas
6       AD802309                          COT                       950699
7       AD481076                          COT                       950699
8       AD481137                          COT                       950699
11      AD481137                    Ecommerce                Medias-Hombre
14      AD481137                dabra-catalog                Medias-Hombre
17      AD481137             Dexter-ecommerce                Medias-Hombre
20      AD481137        Stockcenter-ecommerce                Medias-Hombre
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = (
    df.set_index("PRODUCTNUMBER")
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(
        columns={
            0: "PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME",
            "level_1": "PRODUCTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME",
        }
    )
)

df = df[["PRODUCTNUMBER", "PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME", "PRODUCTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME"]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   PRODUCTNUMBER PRODUCTCATEGORYNAME PRODUCTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME
0       AD802309       Medias-Hombre          Jerarquía principal
1       AD802309              ADIDAS  Jerarquía secundaria marcas
2       AD802309              950699                          COT
3       AD481076              Adidas  Jerarquía secundaria marcas
4       AD481076              950699                          COT
5       AD481137       Medias-Hombre          Jerarquía principal
6       AD481137              Adidas  Jerarquía secundaria marcas
7       AD481137              950699                          COT
8       AD481137       Medias-Hombre                    Ecommerce
9       AD481137       Medias-Hombre                dabra-catalog
10      AD481137       Medias-Hombre             Dexter-ecommerce
11      AD481137       Medias-Hombre        Stockcenter-ecommerce
```

Answer (score 0):

need simple example for answer

**Example**

```
data = {'A': {'a': 'val1', 'b': 'val3'},
        'B': {'a': None, 'b': 'val4'},
        'C': {'a': 'val2', 'b': None}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output(`df`):

```
    A       B       C
a   val1    None    val2
b   val3    val4    None
```

**Code**

when unpivot by `stack`, we can drop null automatic

```
df.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], axis=1)
```

result:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       A       val1
1   a       C       val2
2   b       A       val3
3   b       B       val4
```

Comment: @ Panda Kim, thanks, but I m not getting the output expected:
df=df.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], axis=1)

Comment: what is your desired output in my example?